# Where do methods defined at the top-level exist?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am learning some metaprogramming and I was stuck trying to find a method. Let's say I have the following class:

```
class MyClass
  def self.my_method
  end
  def your_method
  end
end
```

With the following code I can search for each method in the object space:

```
type = Class
name = /^my_method$/
result = ObjectSpace.each_object(type).select do |o|
  o.instance_methods(false).grep(name).size > 0 || o.methods.grep(name).size > 0
end
p result
```

And it finds it showing the following output:

```
[MyClass]
```

As the searcher code also searches for instance methods, it shows the same output when looking for your_method.

Even with if I add a singleton method to an object:

```
mc = MyClass.new
def mc.our_method
end
```

Just changing the searcher like this:

```
type = Object
name = /^our_method$/
result = ObjectSpace.each_object(type).select do |o|
  o.methods.grep(name).size > 0
end
p result
```

It also finds it:

```
[#<MyClass:0x8f86760>]
```

The question is, how do I find a method defined in the top level object? This method:

```
def hidden
end
```

Besides, which is the current class when defining a method like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which is the current class when defining a method like this?

We can easily figure out what object we’re in by inspecting `self` in this top level scope:

```
self        #=> main
self.class  #=> Object
```

So we’re not in a Class, but an instance of Object which is dubbed “main”.

---

> How do I find a method defined in the top level object?

This is where it gets interesting. The top-level scope object in Ruby behaves specially, but it’s relatively easy to discover where a method here defined lives:

```
def foo; :bar; end
method(:foo).owner     #=> Object
Object.new.foo         #=> NoMethodError: private method `foo' called
Object.new.send(:foo)  #=> :bar
```

So methods defined at the top-level are made (private*) instance methods of Object. The reason your ”searcher” cannot find it is because these methods are private, and neither `methods` nor `instance_methods` include private methods, instead you need [`private_methods`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Object.html#method-i-private_methods) and [`private_instance_methods`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Module.html#method-i-private_instance_methods):

```
Object.instance_methods.include?(:foo)          #=> false
Object.private_instance_methods.include?(:foo)  #=> true
```

<sub>* Note that Pry (at least v0.10.1) alters this to make methods defined at top-level in its REPL public.</sub>

Comment: Note to readers (I'm sure Andrew knows this): one could instead use `puts Object.send :private_instance_methods, false #=> foo`. A similar statement (with `false`) shows that no new instance methods have been created in `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

If you had this:

```
def my_method() end

class A
  def self.my_method() end
end

class B < A
  def my_method() end
end

class C
  def my_method() end
end
```

and wanted to find methods named `'my_method'` that you've created, you could do this:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select do |o|
  o.instance_methods(false).include?(:my_method)
end
  #=> [C, B]

ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select do |o|
  o.methods(false).include?(:my_method)
end
  #=> [A]

ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select do |o|
  o.private_instance_methods(false).include?(:my_method)
end
  #=> [Object]
```